# convert HH:MM:SS to seconds or minutes with delphi

Tags: delphi, datetime, time

Can someone advise me on the best way to convert a duration formated HH:MM:SS to seconds or minutes only?

ie. 00:01:49 = 109secs

I´m using this code but not work

```
var
i: real;
j: integer;
begin
i := frac(real(StrToTime('00:00:01')));
j := trunc(frac(real(StrToTime('01:00:00'))) / i );
memo2.lines.add(inttostr(j));
```

when I try the code with 00:10:00 return 599

thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A very flexibel tool for handling durations is `TTimeSpan` found in unit System.TimeSpan. You can get the result in different units (second, minutes, hours, ...) and format that to your needs.

```
var
  timeSpan: TTimeSpan;
begin
  timeSpan := TTimeSpan.Parse('00:01:49');
  memo2.lines.add(Format('%1.1f min', [timeSpan.TotalMinutes]));
end;
```

Answer (score 9):

Using the `DateUtils` unit:

```
WriteLn(SecondOfTheDay(StrToTime('00:10:00')));
WriteLn(MinuteOfTheDay(StrToTime('00:10:00')));
```

Outputs:

```
600
10
```

The reason why your code is not working is that floating point values often can not be exactly represented. To avoid all implementation details about how a `TDateTime` represents the time, use the built in functions in SysUtils and DateUtils, see [Date and Time Support](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Date_and_Time_Support).

Answer (score 4):

Use DecodeTime:

http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/System.SysUtils.DecodeTime

So your code should look like this:

```
DecodeTime(StrToTime('00:00:01'), Hour, Min, Sec, MSec);
```

A function that returns the seconds should look something like this:

```
function GetSeconds(ATimeString: string): Integer;
var
  Hour, Min, Sec, MSec: Word;
begin
  DecodeTime(StrToTime(ATimeString), Hour, Min, Sec, MSec);
  Result := Hour * 3600 + Min * 60 + Sec;
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

Timespan fails for example with '47:50' (overflow, I don't know why). My answer:

```
function GetSecondsFromString(ATimeString: string): Double;
var
  arr: TStringdynArray;
  J, I: Integer;
  tf: TFormatSettings;
begin
  Result:= 0;
  arr:= StrUtils.SplitString(ATimeString, ':');
  I:= High(arr);
  if I < 1 then
    exit;
  if I = 2 then
  begin
    if StrTointDef(arr[0], 0) > 23 then
      exit;
    Result:= StrtoIntDef(arr[0], 0) * 3600;
  end;
  Result:= Result + (StrToIntDef(arr[I - 1], 0) * 60);
  J:= Pos('.', arr[I]);
  if (J > 1) and (J < arr[I].Length) then
  begin
    tf:= TFormatSettings.Create;
    tf.DecimalSeparator:= '.';
    Result:= Result + StrToFloat('0' + Copy(arr[I], Pos('.', arr[I])), tf);
    arr[I]:= Copy(arr[I], 1, Pos('.', arr[I]) - 1);
  end;
  Result:= Result + StrToIntDef(arr[I], 0);
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not a standalone answer but just an extension to Uwe's answer. Upvote his answer.

```
{ Converts a string formatted like 'hh:mm:ss' to seconds.
  Returns -1 is the string does not contain a valid time. 

    StringToSeconds('00:01:30')     // returns 90 (sec)
    StringToSeconds('01:30')        // returns 5400 (sec)
    StringToSeconds('10')           // returns 864000 (sec)
    StringToSeconds('1.30')         // returns -1
    StringToSeconds('x')            // returns -1                           }

function StringToSeconds(CONST s: String): integer;
VAR
  TimeSpan: TTimeSpan;
begin
  TRY
   TimeSpan:= System.TimeSpan.TTimeSpan.Parse(s);
   Result := round(TimeSpan.TotalSeconds);
  EXCEPT
   Result:= -1;
  end;
end;
```